# Where can I find a map of all the canal boat routes in Bangkok?

Tags: thailand, maps, bangkok, riverboats

I read on https://www.hotels.com/go/thailand/bangkok-river-boats-ferries#Canal_boats ([mirror](https://archive.vn/Wabb3)):

> These **large, loud, spluttering canal boats can be found chugging up and down Bangkok's many canals**. The city's largest khlong (canal) is [Saen Seab Canal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khlong_Saen_Saep), which dissects Bangkok from the Old City in the west to Ramkamheng in the far east.
>
> Canal taxi boats have exclusive use of this large artery of water,
> which means traffic is never a problem. The frequency of these boats
> changes throughout the day, generally ranging from 5 to 20 minutes
> between vessels. One journey costs between 9 baht and 19 baht
> depending on the distance.
>
> In the early mornings and late afternoons, these canal boats are a
> vital transport link for office workers travelling from downtown
> Bangkok to the eastern suburbs. Seating becomes scarce around these
> times, but it offers an intriguing glimpse into the locals' daily
> routine in the urban jungle.

Where can I find a map of all the [canal boat](https://www.hotels.com/go/thailand/bangkok-river-boats-ferries#Canal_boats) routes (ideally with their stops) in Bangkok?

The only map I could find is for the [Khlong Saen Saep boat service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khlong_Saen_Saep_boat_service), which operates on the [Khlong Saen Saep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khlong_Saen_Saep) canal:

[image]

([image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bangkok-saensaep-map.svg))

---

Note that canal boats aren't the same as [river boats or river ferries](https://www.hotels.com/go/thailand/bangkok-river-boats-ferries#Express_Boat_river_taxis) ([mirror](https://archive.vn/Wabb3)).

This is a canal boat:

[image]

Comment: Particularly for tourist places, I was going to suggest a [Nancy Chandler](https://nancychandler.net/index.html) map, but sadly Nancy died a few years ago and the business has ceased trading. Although it seems you can still buy her maps, including on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Nancy-Chandlers-Map-Bangkok-28th/dp/6168195009). Their website also has digital download options.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, **no such map exists**, because:

1. the canal boat network is actually much more sparse than the quoted page suggests,
2. it's not integrated to the rest of Bangkok's public transport system (ticketing etc),
3. it's not even a single network, but a few largely separately owned and operated lines.

At time of writing, the only routes I'm aware of are:

- The [Saen Saep line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khlong_Saen_Saep_boat_service) you already mentioned, easily the busiest and best-known of the bunch
- The [Khlong Phadung Krung Kasem](https://www.bangkokpost.com/thailand/special-reports/1898705/canal-service-gets-new-lease-on-life) line between Hualamphong and Thewes pier on the Chao Phraya; this one is quite new and potentially useful even to tourists
- The [Khlong Phasi Charoen line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khlong_Phasi_Charoen_boat_service) in Thonburi, between Phetkasem 49 and Wat Paknam Phasi Charoen, largely paralleling the MRT Blue Line to the north, although I'm not sure this is still running (their [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Pasrijaroenboat) is gone)